How do I specify the settings for Neo4j for VS Code extension?
I'm new to Neo4j and I was trying to get set up with the VS Code extension for some highlighting and autocompletion. It looks like the highlighting works decently, but it doesn't seem to pull any information from the database so I'm still typing everything out manually. I don't even have the option to specify extension settings in .vscode/settings.json to potentially link it to my database according to the documentation here.
I have a free AuraDB instance that I'm trying to mess around with.
I can't seem to figure out what I'm missing here?

Follow the instructions here for defining and enabling connections. On the same page there is a list of upcoming features.
Here is a screenshot of the dialog:

